# Qual é a tradução e o significado de "evangelist"?

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês

Algumas pessoas são entituladas "*evangelist*" de alguma coisa. Veja:

- [Jerry Nixon, Microsoft Developer Evangelist](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/)
- [Matthew Maxwell, JavaScript Evangelist](https://blog.bloc.io/interview-with-javascript-evangelist-matthew-maxwell/)

Geralmente vejo esse termo sendo usado junto à tecnologia.

Os dicionários [traduzem essa palavra](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english-portuguese/evangelist) como "evangelista", mas os significados que encontrei passam a não fazer sentido nos contextos dados acima.

> [**evangelista**](http://www.aulete.com.br/evangelista)
>   1. cada um dos quatro autores dos quatros livros do Evangelho: Mateus, Marcos, Lucas e João;
>   2. aquele que evangeliza ou divulga uma doutrina em pregações;
>   3. seguidor de Igreja Evangélica;
>   4. que evangeliza ou divulga uma doutrina em pregações;
>   5. que segue os ensinamentos da Igreja Evangélica.

Como não encontrei um significado nem no inglês e nem no português, segui a etimologia da palavra até o grego *euangelizesthai*, entretanto sem sucesso já que reitera o sentido gospel.

Nesse contexto, qual é o significado de *evangelist*? E qual seria uma boa tradução?

Comment: A tradução pode ser literal e pegar um significado parecido com o item 2->
aquele que evangeliza ou divulga uma doutrina em pregações. Normalmente nas tecnologias de desenvolvimento é alguém responsável por trazer as informações sobre essa tecnologia em palestras e etc. Nem sempre é realmente quem as usa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De fato, o termo *evangelista* ainda carrega uma forte conotação religiosa, porém também começou a ser usado para os divulgadores de determinada tecnologia.

A wikipedia usa o termo [**Evangelista Tecnológico**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelista_tecnol%C3%B3gico) para designar alguém que é *"um especialista em convencer as massas para a adoção de uma determinada tecnologia ou plataforma tecnológica"*. O mesmo artigo cita alguns exemplos:

> Evangelistas tecnológicos profissionais são geralmente empregados por empresas que desejam estabelecer suas plataformas tecnológicas proprietárias ou livres como o "padrão" do mercado.
>
> Outros exemplos de evangelistas tecnológicos são aqueles profissionais que advogam a utilização de plataformas livres, como o Linux, e também aqueles que defendem plataformas proprietárias, como o Windows. Ou também aqueles que advogam a utilização de computação em nuvem, redes sociais e quaisquer inovações tecnológicas.

Muitos sites e artigos traduzem como *"Evangelista de [nome da tecnologia ou produto]"*, ou simplesmente *evangelista*. Porém este uso ainda não parece ter sido assimilado pelos dicionários:

- no [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/evangelista), o mais próximo que encontrei foi: *Anunciador e preconizador de uma boa doutrina.* (considerando que muitas tecnologias ganham "adoradores" em um nível considerado até "religioso", não me espanta que tenham escolhido um termo com conotação religiosa para tal)
- na [Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/evangelista) também há um significado parecido: *aquele que preconiza uma doutrina nova* (também considerando o aspecto "religioso" que algumas tecnologias alcançam - sei que é uma visão meio caricata e estereotipada, mas enfim)

Consultei outros dicionários também, com resultados similares (todos ligados a religião/doutrina). Creio que este novo significado - relacionado a tecnologia - ainda não foi reconhecido, embora seja bastante usado.

---

Um outro termo que também já vi - e que acredito ser uma boa alternativa de tradução - é **divulgador**, e parece se encaixar na definição da wikipedia: alguém que divulga determinada tecnologia e promove o seu uso.